# connecting to database using php mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

This is my connection file

```
<?php
$mysqli= @new mysqli("localhost","root","","ngo_sharda");
if($mysqli->connect_errno)
{
    printf ("connection failed %s \n",mysqli_connect_error());



} 

?>
```

And this is my class file...

```
<?php
include('../connection.php');
 class operation
 {

     private $title;

/*
function __construct()
{

    $this->title=$m;


}
*/
function setvalues()
{
    $this->title=$m;


}


function insert()
  { 



  $q="insert into menus(title,link) values('kumar','great')";

  //$result=mysqli_query($mysqli,$q);


 $result= $mysqli->query($q);

  if($result==1)
  {

     echo "inserted"; 

 }

   else 
     {

     echo "not inserted";

     }

   }



 }

?>
```

if i am trying to create a insert function inside the class i am getting error that i am calling query on a non object.

how can i call $mysqli object directly inside this class in insert function without passing it as an argument in any function or in constructor.

Comment: Lose the `@`.  You should not be suppressing errors that may arise.

Comment: Why don't you want to pass it through the constructor?

Comment: Also, why are there so many blank lines in the PHP file you pasted here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would load the database connection *inside* the constructor so you can make it a member of the class.

```
<?php
    class operation{
        private $title;
        private $mysqli;

        function __construct(){
            // include basically copies & pastes the file
            include('../connection.php');

            // $mysqli exists inside this function, let's make it
            // available in the rest of the class
            $this->mysqli = $mysqli;

            //$this->title = $m;
        }

        function setvalues(){
            $this->title = $m;
        }


        function insert(){ 
            $q = "insert into menus(title,link) values('kumar','great')";

            // Now we can access `$this->mysqli` and everything should work
            $result = $this->mysqli->query($q);

            if($result==1){
                echo "inserted"; 
            }
            else{
                echo "not inserted";
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: TO rocket hazmat but i dnt want to load my connection file in constructor since i want to make a resuable script with maintaining the standard of oops concept.....i want a  technique where i can directly call my connection.